# How to ignore toggling the highlight of freespace in Javascript bingo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a "buzzword bingo" game and am having difficulty with ignoring the onClick for the freespace which should always remain highlighted. I am using Javascript to build the table for me, so applying the css isn't coming easy to me. Here is the js:

```
function calcRowSize(words) {
    return Math.sqrt(words.length);
}

function isEndOfRow(rowSize, index) {
    return Number.isInteger(index + 1 / rowSize);
}

function isStartOfRow(rowSize, index) {
    return Number.isInteger(index / rowSize);
}

function isFreeSpace(wordCount, index) {
    var freeSpaceIndex = Math.floor(wordCount / 2);
    return freeSpaceIndex == index;
}

function insertData(words) {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.innerHTML=""; // Initialize the table



    var tr=""; // Intitialize the table row
    var rowSize = calcRowSize(words);
    words.forEach((word, index) => {
        // Handle 4 scenarios:
        // - [start of row] start table row & insert table data
        // - [end of row] insert table data & end table row
        // - [is the free space] insert blank table data
        // - [middle of row] insert table data
        if (isStartOfRow(rowSize, index)) {
            tr+= '<tr>' ;
            tr+= '<td>' + word + '</td>';
        } else if (isEndOfRow(rowSize, index)) {
            tr+= '<td>' + word + '</td>';
            tr+= '</tr>';
        } else if (isFreeSpace(words.length, index)) {
            tr+= '<td><img src="images/paw.svg"></td>';
        } else {
            tr+= '<td>' + word + '</td>';
        }
        // tr+= '<tr>';
        // tr+= '<td>' + word + '</td>';
        // tr+= '</tr>';
    });
    table.innerHTML += tr;
}

insertData(shuffle(words));

// Toggle highlighted cells
table.onclick = function(event) {
    highlight(event.target);
};

function highlight(td) {
    td.classList.toggle('highlight');
}
```

What is the best way to go about achieving this?

Comment: Give every freespace cell an extra class when building the markup for the table. Then adapt your CSS accordingly - or change the `highlight` event listener to check for that class.